# Returning results with callbacks

Tags: javascript, node.js, callback

I'm trying to query a database, then make an array of objects from the results, turn them into a JSON object.

I'm not used to Javascript's asynchronous nature and I'm really confused about how to implement something that needs to work synchronously.  I know I probably need to use callbacks, but after looking at many tutorials I'm only left more confused.

This is the code without callbacks:

```html
var foreignTable = (tablename,idArr)=>{
 var dataArray = [];
 //call a query for each of the ids
 var objectToAdd;
 for(var id of idArr){
  objectToAdd = queryForeignTable(tablename,id);
  dataArray.push(objectToAdd);
 }
 return dataArray;
 
connection.end();
}; 

var queryForeignTable = (tablename,id)=>{
 connection.query("SELECT * FROM "+tablename+" WHERE id="+id, function (error, results, fields) {
 if(error)throw error;
 var objectToAddToArray={};
 //Go through each field in a result and make the object 
 for(packet of fields){
  var label = packet.name;
  objectToAddToArray[label] = results[0][label];
 }
 
 return objectToAddToArray;

});
};

var arrayOfDrivers = foreignTable("driver",[1,2]);
 
outputJson["drive"]=arrayOfDrivers;

console.log(outputJson);  // { drive: [ undefined, undefined ] }
```

I attempted `foreignTable(tablename, idArr, callback)` with the callback calling `queryForeignTable` with no luck.

Can someone explain how I can get this piece of code working with callbacks?

Comment: Probably you want to check *ES7 async functions (async/await)*. E.g. this [presentation](http://rossboucher.com/await/)

Comment: learnyounode is a great tutorial, if you haven't already tried it https://github.com/workshopper/learnyounode

Answer (score 0):

> A callback function is a function passed into another function as an argument, which is then invoked inside the outer function to complete some kind of routine or action.

from [MDN: Callback function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Callback_function)

Callbacks are a way of telling a function what to do next, as in "after you're done, run this function".

For example:

```
first = function (callback) {
    console.log("First!");
    callback();
}

second = function () {
    console.log("Second!");
}

first(second);
```

Will produce:

```
First!
Second!
```

You can also use anonymous function to product the same result:

```
first(function() {
    console.log("Second!")
});
```

Regarding the specific example from your question, you are correct that you need to use callbacks a bit differently. Rather than using a `return` statement in each of your two functions, you'll need to use a callback. `connection.query` is asynchronously coming back with your results as `results`, but you can't `return` them to your `queryForeignTable` function. Instead, give `queryForeignTable` a callback function to run. The same idea goes for your `foreignTable` function.

I'm not connected to your database, obviously, so I stubbed a DB connection and simplified what you're trying to do, but it should look something like this:

```
// Stubbed DB connection
var connection = {};
connection.query = (id, cb) => {
  var results = [
    {
      id: id,
      name: 'Name of ' + id,
    },
  ];
  cb(null, results);
};

var foreignTable = (ids, cb) => {
  var data = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < ids.length; i++) {
    queryForeignTable(ids[i], (error, obj) => {
      data.push(obj);
      if (i == ids.length - 1) {
        cb(null, data);
      }
    });
  }
};

var queryForeignTable = (id, cb) => {
  connection.query(id, (error, results) => {
    if (error) {
      cb(error, null);
    }
    cb(null, results[0]);
  });
};

foreignTable([1, 2], (error, data) => {
  if (error) {
    console.error(error);
  }
  console.log(data);
});
```

That produces:

```
[ { id: 1, name: 'Name of 1' }, { id: 2, name: 'Name of 2' } ]
```

In essence, when you have an urge to `return` some value(s) from a function in an asynchronous way, give the function a callback parameter, then invoke that callback with your return values.

You can run the code here: https://repl.it/K0YI/3

Answer (score 0):

When you have an asynchronous call, like `connection.query(statement, callback)`, then whatever you want to do with the results of that call needs to be done within the callback.

Bear in mind that async functions don't return the final value that you generally want (usually they return `undefined`). Instead of using a return value, you pass a callback as a way of saying, "when you're finished, carry on and do this with the results", aka. continuation-passing style.

One of the challenges in your code is that you're issuing separate queries for each ID, and then aggregating the results into an array of responses. This means you'll need to check when all the queries have completed, and only then proceed to display the final results.

Here's your example, re-written, commented, and simplified. Hopefully this helps to explain how the control flow works.

```
// Read row IDs 1 and 2 from the "driver" table.
readTable("driver", [1, 2], displayData);

// Print the results.
function displayData (arrayOfDrivers) {
    console.log(arrayOfDrivers);
}

// Read all rows matching IDs in `idArray` from `tableName`,
// put results into an array, and finally invoke `callback`.
function readTable (tablename, idArray, callback) {
    var resultsArray = [];

    // Queue up all the async queries.
    for (var id of idArray){
        queryTable(table, id, handleResponse);
    }

    // A query finished, so handle the result.
    function handleResponse (error, results, fields) {
        if (error) {
            throw error;
        }

        // Add the query result to array of results.
        resultsArray.push(results[0]);

        // Check if all queries are done.
        if (resultsArray.length === idArray.length) {
            // Invoke the callback with the resultsArray.
            // The callback is in fact the `displayData` function.
            callback(resultsArray);
        }
    }
}

// Execute a query, using the `cb` callback to handle the response.
function queryForeignTable (tablename, id, cb) {
    var query = "SELECT * FROM " + tablename + " WHERE id=" + id;
    connection.query(query, cb);
}
```

Note that the `handleResponse` function is defined within the scope of the `readTable` function, so it can access the variables in `readTable`s scope, such as `resultsArray` and `callback`.

Hope that helps.